# how can i delete dynamic array created in a function

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I have to write a program (not using vector, nor using structures nor OOP) which calculates the sum and the product of two polynomials.
Here is my code:

```cpp
//Task 4.19 & 4.20
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
double* definePoly(char& symbol, char& coef, int& k)
{
    std::cout << "deg(" << symbol << "(x)) = ";
    std::cin >> k;
    symbol++;
    double* a = new double[k];
    for (int i = k; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << coef << "_{" << i << "} = ";
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    coef++;
    return a;
}
void printPoly(int n, double* P, char& symbol)
{
    symbol--;
    std::cout << symbol << "(x)=";
    for (int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (P[i] != 0)
        {
            if (P[i] > 0)
            {
                std::cout << '+';
            }
            std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
            std::cout.precision(2);
            std::cout << P[i] << ".x^{" << i << "}";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    symbol++;
}
double* sumPoly(double* a, int n, double* b, int m, char& symbol)
{ // Task 4.19
    symbol++;
    double* c = new double[(n + m + abs(n - m)) / 2];
    if (n > m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        for (int i = m + 1; i <= n; i++) c[i] = a[i];
    }
    else if (n < m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        for (int i = n + 1; i <= m; i++) c[i] = b[i];
    }
    else for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    return c;
}
double* prodPoly(double* a, int n, double* b, int m, char& symbol)
{ // Task 4.20
    symbol++;
    double* d = new double[n + m];
    for (int p = 0; p <= n + m; p++)
    {
        d[p] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++)
                if (i + j == p) d[p] = d[p] + a[i] * b[j];
    }
    return d;
}
int main()
{
    int n, m;
    char symbol('P'), coef('a');

    double* firstPoly = definePoly(symbol, coef, n);
    printPoly(n, firstPoly, symbol);

    double* secondPoly = definePoly(symbol, coef, m);
    printPoly(m, secondPoly, symbol);

    double* sum = sumPoly(firstPoly, n, secondPoly, m, symbol);
    std::cout << "Sum:\n";
    printPoly((n + m + abs(n - m)) / 2, sum, symbol);

    double* prod = prodPoly(firstPoly, n, secondPoly, m, symbol);
    std::cout << "Product:\n";
    printPoly(n + m, prod, symbol);

    /*delete[] firstPoly;
    delete[] secondPoly;
    delete[] sum;
    delete[] prod;*/

    return 0;
}
```

It works *perfectly*, but when I uncomment the deleting, visual studio tells me that there is an error, otherwise there are leaks.

How can I delete/release the memory in order to solve this problem?

Comment: ***What*** are the "error" you get if you try to `delete[]` the arrays? Are you sure you don't go out of bounds of the allocated memory? The `definePoly` function *definitely* go out of bounds.

Comment: "visual studio tells me that there is an error" what error? please include it in the question

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the `delete`s? This should work on the first glance. Also, necessary comment: use `std::vector` instead of manual memory management.

Comment: compiles fine here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nMPPpQ4LmRyipfcv

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The problems are most likely run-time errors and crashes.

Comment: is it possible that the errors you get are runtime errors due to out-of-bounds access? Loops like that one `for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)` look wrong for going till `<= m`. In an array with `m` elements the last valid index is `m-1` not `m`

Comment: Runs fine too (with the `delete[]` enabled)

Comment: You have an "off by one" error in your `definePoly()`, since it dynamically allocates an array of `k` elements, then the loop sets values for `k+1` elements of that array.   That causes undefined behaviour.   One of the many common symptoms of such undefined behaviour is messing up the working of operator `delete`.    I haven't looked at other functions, but would not be surprised if they have similar "off by one" errors.

Comment: "It works perfectly" please defines what should be the "perfect" output and and your current output.

Comment: If the delete of a heap allocated pointer isn't working it tells you that your program has a bug, not that you were doing the delete wrongly. New programmers often think bugs are caused by deletes, but almost always something has gone wrong some time before the delete and that is the real bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> double* a = new double[k];
> for (int i = k;
>     std::cin >> a[i];
> ```

The index of the last element of an array of `k` elements is `k - 1` You access the arrays out of bounds in all your loops (this is just one of them) . The behaviour of the program is undefined.

> how can i delete dynamic array created in a function

Just like you would delete a dynamic array created outside of a function, and just like you've attempted to delete it:

> ```
> delete[] firstPoly; // etc
> ```

But you must make sure that your program doesn't corrupt its own memory with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is it considered okay to use `new` and `delete` in different scopes, so to say? The `new` is called in one function but `delete` is called in another function.